# Scrape hotels from tripadvisor ..how to get hotels from all pages like 1 to 10 pages and store it?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

My code is showing the first page of hotels. Why isn't it showing more?

```
import csv

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hotels=[]
i=0

url0 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-     Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

r = requests.get(url0)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")with open('hotels_Data.csv','wb') as file:

for link in soup.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
    print('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-' + link.get('href'))
    print(link.string)


for i in range(20):
   while int(i) <= (20):
    i = str(i)

    url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + i + '-  Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = r1.text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
    for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title','price'}):
        print('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g294212-' +    link.get('href'))
        print(link.string)
        for link in soup.select("a.reference.internal"):
            url1 = link["href"]
            absolute_url = urljoin(base_url, url1)

            print(url1, absolute_url)       
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in hotels:
            writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])                                                
break
```

Comment: When you asked TripAdvisor if you're allowed to do that, didn't they offer you an access via an API?

Comment: No,they only provide the API for the people who has some business(for official use)..... i am a student n i just need some data for my project..

Comment: You could try using something like Selenium to find the 'next page' button on the page. Takes a bit longer than BS because it actually opens a browser window to interact with, but is a quick fix to your problem

Comment: portal use values 30, 60, 90, 120, etc. not 1, 2, 3, as next page number - because there are 30 offers on page.

Comment: @furas can u show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check links to next pages at the bottom of page - this portal doesn't use page numbers - `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. - but offer offset - `0`, `30`, `60`, `90` ect. (because it displays 30 offers on page)

So you have to use values `0`, `30`, `60`, `90`, etc. in url

```
"...-oa" + offset + "-Dubai_Emirate..."
```

You can use ie. `range(0, 250, 30)` to get values `0`, `30`, `60`, `90`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for offset in range(0, 250, 30):
    print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')

    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + str(offset) + '-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
          print(link.text)
```

But there can be more offers than 250 so you have to get link to last page to get correct value instead of `250`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

offset = 0
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + str(offset) + '-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'last'}):
    page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
    last_offset = int(page_number) * 30
    print('last offset:', last_offset)
```

And use `last_offset+1` in `range(0, last_offset+1, 30)`

---

EDIT: Restaurants use JavaScript and AJAX to load data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

size = 30

# direct url - doesn't have expected information
#url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g187791-Rome_Lazio.html'

# url used by AJAX
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/RestaurantSearch?Action=PAGE&geo=187791&ajax=1&itags=10591&sortOrder=relevance&o=a' + str(size) + '&availSearchEnabled=true&eaterydate=2017_04_27&date=2017-04-28&time=20%3A00%3A00&people=2'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

link = soup.find_all('a')[-1]
page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
last_offset = int(page_number) * size # *30
print('last offset:', last_offset)

offset = link.get('data-offset')
offset = int(offset) + size # +30
print('offset:', offset)
```

Comment: i need your help can u please tell me how to get the offset of restaurants from tripadvisor? because i used your above method for hotels it worked perfectly but in case of restaurants it is not working. help me please.

Comment: @Hifzaahmad what means "not working" ? I didn't check page but restaurants can use different tags or different paginations or even they can use JavaScript. It is nothing strange.